# Python, Iterate through JSON files and skip blank files

Tags: python, json

I have some python code that iterates through several JSON file and converts them to CSV.

Most of the files look like this:

```
{
    "resultSet": {
        "totalRecords": "2",
        "agentLogins": [
            {
                "phoneNumber": "99999",
                "callerId": "999999999",
                "stationId": "99999999",
                "stationName": "",
                "loginDate": "2020-09-17T15:25:34.410Z"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "99999",
                "callerId": "99999999",
                "stationId": "999999",
                "stationName": "",
                "loginDate": "2020-09-17T17:22:48.613Z"
            }
           
        ]
    }
}
```

And the code works fine. But a few of the files don't have any records and look like this:

```
{
    "resultSet": {
        "totalRecords": "0",
        
    }
}
```

My code will error when a record is blank because it doesn't have an agentLogins key. Here is my code:

```
import json 
import csv 
  
with open('agentLogins.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
  
agentLogins = data['resultSet']['agentLogins']
  
data_file = open('agentLogins.csv', 'w') 
  
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file) 
  
count = 0
  
for emp in agentLogins: 
    if count == 0: 
  
        header = emp.keys() 
        csv_writer.writerow(header) 
        count += 1
  
    csv_writer.writerow(emp.values()) 
  
data_file.close()
```

I am just looking for a way to skip those blank files.

Thanks

Comment: Don't add logic to skip "empty" files (they are not really empty, are they?) but have your code properly handle optional keys being optional, e.g. using an `in` check or `dict.get`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the presence of the `agentLogins` key before you try to access its value:

```
with open('agentLogins.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file)

if 'agentLogins' not in data['resultSet']:
    # skip this file
```

Comment: Great!  If you like, you can click the green checkmark to accept this as an answer :-)